# Android SQLite DB Open for Application Lifetime

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-lifecycle, android

I know there have been a bunch of questions and answers on this one already, but I couldn't find any conclusive answer that says what I want to do is OK.

Basically I want to have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` that gets instantiated in `MyApplication.onCreate()` (I extend `Application`). That way, my code only ever has to call the singleton's `getWritableDatabase()` and I don't have to worry about managing whether the db is open or close, or worry about tearing down and building up connections.

I gather that the connection will remain open until I call the singleton's `close()` which I plan on never doing, so the connection will remain open as long as the application is running. When the application is killed, the whole process gets killed, so the db connection will get killed with it, as well as any resources tied up with the db. Then, the next time the application is run, I instantiate the singleton again, and go on with my business.

Is this a bad idea? Can I run into issues with not closing the db connection even if the process is killed? The reason I would like to do this is because a lot of my code is not strongly coupled to `Activity` lifecycles, and it would be a real headache to manage the db lifetime based on it.

Comment: just my 2 cents: `This class makes it easy for ContentProvider implementations to defer opening and upgrading the database until first use, to avoid blocking application startup with long-running database upgrades.` from SQLiteOpenHelper's doc ... it is one of the multiple reasons(among others like Loaders, "requery", update data from other applications components like Service) why i'm using ContentProvider for db operation...

Comment: I definitely thought about using `ContentProvider` but I ended up not going with it because it seemed like the wrong abstraction, even though it would give some of the functionality that I need.

Comment: `Is this a bad idea? Can I run into issues with not closing the db connection even if the process is killed?` i don't think so ... similar situation we have in ContentProvider(there is no callback like onStop/onClose, the place where you can close db connection) ... of course if application will be killed in the middle of some "write to file" operation you will ended with corrupted db but again it will happend in ContentProvider approach too.

Comment: Even if you take a look at google's example on using sqlitehelper, they never close the db. If you read the documentation for sqlite db on android, it mentions that the android os itself treat the database as a file and when you're not using it anymore (when the app is killed) the os itself takes care of closing the database file for you.